# Changing the compatibility mode of IE programmatically when working with shdocvw.InternetExplorer

Tags: internet-explorer

I have read many forums about this. I am not working on this server side nor on the client side. I am working with the Quality Assurance department of my company. We have an in house testing software built in the .Net Framework for testing our companies various websites. We prefer our testing for Internet Explorer be done in Version 9.

The problem I am facing is that a specific site that we test, uses the meta tag to set IE to use compatibility mode 7 (IE 7). When this gets set, the only way to reset it to 9 is to manually go into IE development tools and switch it back to IE9. I have read about using the registry key value to switch it, and have tried without success. I was also exploring the idea of trying to some how manipulate the HTMLDocument to change that or insert in the the head tag, the meta tag and set it to IE9.

I would appreciate anyone's suggestions or links to helpful articles or forums. We are using the ShDocVW.InternetExplorer to run our tests along with the mshtml library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed to find a way to do this on the automation side as our devs aren't always willing to do things like that for the QA department. I came up with an easy fix, for tests that run in older compatibility mode of IE, after those tests finish, I just have them create a new browser instance and navigate to WWW.Google.Com as that uses the meta tag like you were suggesting to IE=edge. Since our machines are set up to run IE9 and nothing higher, this will force it back to compatibility mode IE9.